# Random Variable being $F$-measurable

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-variables

It is said the Random variable is $F$-measurable if $\{X\leq x\}$ is an element of $F$. Is $X$ not $F$measurable once it is not less than or equal to $1$ $x$ or only for all?

Comment: $X$ is $\mathcal F$-measurable if the *set* $\{X\le x\}$ is an element of $\mathcal F$ for *every* $x$. To be measurable means that all events of the form $\{X\le x\}$ will have a probability assigned to them.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what a $\sigma$-algebra is?  It is a collection of *subsets* of the sample space $\Omega$.  In particular, it is a collection of subsets that a) contains $\Omega$ as an element, b) is closed under set complement, and c) is closed under countable unions.

The purpose of a $\sigma$-algebra is to act as the *domain* of a measure $P$.  So the measure (often called a probability measure) $P$ is a function from our $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ to $[0,1]$.  When you input an element of $\mathcal{F}$ (which is a subset of $\Omega$), the measure outputs a number that we interpret as how likely that "event" is to occur.  The elements of $\mathcal{F}$ (which are subsets of $\Omega$) are called events.

Now, we say a function $X : \Omega \to \Bbb R$ is *measurable* if for each $\alpha \in \Bbb R$, $\{\omega \mid X(\omega) \leq \alpha \}$ (which is another way of writing $X^{-1}(-\infty, \alpha]$) is an event, i.e., if it is in $\mathcal{F}$, i.e., if we are able to assign a probability to it by evaluating it under the $P$ function/probability measure.

The reason we say $X$ is measurable under this definition is because it allows us to integrate the function $X$ using the Lebesgue integral.  Have you taken any analysis courses that introduce integration using measure theory?  If not, I think once you do, that will help you understand these definitions much more.  I actually think you should understand that material first before attempting to understand probability theory using measure theory, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: No, we didn't at my university. Someone once told me they think they rush into courses. So no.

Comment: @Mi-leeWilson That's too bad.  Studying integration via measure theory in an analysis course would be an excellent prereq for this course.  Just remember that a main reason we want a function to be measurable is that we can then integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

A random varible is defined on a probability space which consists of a sample space $\Omega$, a $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}$ on $\Omega$ and a measure $P:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow [0,1]$.

In this case, $X$ is a random variable if for ever $x\in\mathbb{R}$, 
$[X\le x]\in \mathcal{F}$.  To wit, $X$ is a measurable function on the measure space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$.